# AppCompatButton subclass has transparent background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I've created a lay out with button which appear with grey background color as default,

```
<Button ... />
```

but then If I create custom button class,

```
<com.project.MyButton ... />
```

the background which was previously grey becomes transparent.

```
public class MyButton extends AppCompatButton {

    private static final String TAG = MyButton.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Not sure why.

Comment: Add whole entry of `<com.project.MyButton` in xml with question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without your layout XML, but I think that this is a case against telescoping constructors. Instead of calling `this(context, attrs, 0)` etc., call the `super` directly. What may be happening is that you are failing to pick up a default button style. Your `MyButton` should look like this:

**MyButton.java**

```
public class MyButton extends AppCompatButton {

    private static final String TAG = MyButton.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Take a look a two of the constructors in `AppCompatButton.java`:

```
public AppCompatButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, attr.buttonStyle);
}

public AppCompatButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(TintContextWrapper.wrap(context), attrs, defStyleAttr);
   ...other stuff...
}
```

The constructor `AppCompatButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` incorporates a `defStyleAttr` of `attr.buttonStyle`. When you call `super(context,attrs)`, you will get this style. When you telescope constructors, you actually call `AppCompatButton(context, attrs, 0)` and miss the contribution of the default style.